# Cross section from transition rate, finite and infinite volume normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In scattering theory, the transition rate is expressed in terms of the transition operator

$$\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\rho_f|T_{fi}|^2 \,,$$

and the cross section is obtained by dividing the transition rate by the incident flux $F_{inc}$.

In my Quantum Mechanics class, the teacher proceeded by using "infinite volume normalization for the free states, $\langle\vec{p}'|\vec{p}\rangle = \delta(\vec{p} - \vec{p}')$", where we adopted $\rho_f = d^3k_f/dE_f$ (for a single free particle escaping to infinity)
and $F_{inc} = v_i/(2\pi\hbar)^3$, $v_i = \hbar k_i/m_i$. With those definitions one can obtain:

$$d\sigma = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|T_{fi}|^2\frac{\rho_f}{F_{inc}} = (2\pi)^4\hbar^2m_im_f\frac{k_f}{k_i}|T_{fi}|^2 d\Omega\,.$$

I didn't understand how the flux and state density come from this normalization, mainly because the units (of the flux and state density) don't seem to make sense, so i tried to to obtain the same result by using a finite volume $L^3$ normalization for the final free state. By imposing periodic boundary conditions on the volume $L^3$, the final state density is

$$\rho_f = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^3\frac{d^3k_{f}}{dE_f} = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^3 p_f^2d\Omega_f\frac{dp_f}{dE_f} = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^3\hbar m_fk_fd\Omega \,.$$

Using an incident flux $F_{inc} = v_i/L^3 = \hbar k_i /m_iL^3$ and the state density above, I obtained a different result for the cross section, different by a factor of $(L/2\pi\hbar)^6$:

$$d\sigma = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^6(2\pi)^4\hbar^2m_im_f\frac{k_f}{k_i}|T_{fi}|^2 d\Omega\,.$$

What this "infinite volume normalization" is all about, and how can the same result be obtained with the finite volume normalization?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is that I failed to consider that the matrix element $|T_{if}|^2$ changes with the normalization.